# Oracle PDB broken after upgrade from 12.1 to 12.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, upgrade

We upgraded our development environment Oracle 12.1 RDBMS to 12.2 version. The CDB contained 3 PDBs of which 2 upgraded nicely but 1 did not. The resulting situation is that during the upgrade SYSTEM and SYSAUX tablespaces ran out of space which caused all the packages etc also to fail. Now we cannot rebuild the internals because of the lack of space (ORA-65114: space usage in container is too high) and we cannot expand/add or frankly do any operations due to broken system data e.g:

```
SQL> alter pluggable database storage unlimited;
alter pluggable database storage unlimited
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'LBACSYS.LBAC$BEFORE_ALTER'
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 2
ORA-65114: space usage in container is too high
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called:
"LBACSYS.LBAC_EVENTS"
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

We have tried to create a new PDB from the failed PDB (did not work) and create a new PDB and move the old PDB's USERS tablespace files under the new PDB (using the same names, but also did not work due to mismatching checksums on PDB start).

The PDB seems to be usable by the end users but no management activities can be performed (expdp or even just looking at a table metadata in Sqldeveloper).

Is there any chance for recovery at all or should we start looking up backups?

Comment: You said you can not expand/add, but I see no error message or any further description. So what exactly happens when  you try this in the PDB: `alter pluggable database storage unlimited;`?

Comment: Thank you Balazs for the comment - I have edited the main entry. Any corrective or other action (using expdp e.g) results in similar errors. It seems to be chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: And what happens, if you do the same, but open the pluggable database in upgrade mode? `alter pluggable database pdb... open upgrade;` Upgrade mode disables system triggers.

Comment: That did the trick. In UPGRADE mode I was able to set the storage limit, resize tablespaces and rebuild broken packages. Thank you, Balazs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Balazs Papp, opening the PDB in UPGRADE mode did the trick. After that I was able to set the STORAGE limit, resize the tablespaces and rebuild broken packages.